# module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run' with Python 3.9.4

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to get started learning asyncio, but I can't get simple examples to work. Previous posts about this error point to using a python version prior to 3.7, but here you can see that I'm using the latest build (3.9.4). Entering the code directly into the python interpreter works, but running it from a file will not. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

command line output

```
> python3 --version
Python 3.9.4
> python3 asyncio.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mmolesworth/courses/asyncio.py", line 22, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run'
```

asyncio.py contents

```
import asyncio

async def count():
    print("One")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Two")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(count(), count(), count())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    s = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"{__file__} executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
```

Comment: Your file is named `asyncio.py`, rename it.

Comment: Did you name the file `asyncio`? That'll make your program import itself.

Comment: @SuperStormer is *that* really the canonical dupe? I almost want to write up something fresh for this common problem.

Comment: I just picked a similar question with the same solution, you can make this the canonical if you want.